# How to get return type of annotated method in annotation processor?

Tags: java, annotations

I am learning to write custom annotations. I have a simple annotation that needs to verify if the return type of a method matches return type specified in the annotation. Below is the code.

Annotation code:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ReturnCheck {
    String value() default "void";
}
```

Annotation processor:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.rajesh.customannotations.ReturnCheck")
public class ReturnCheckProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

        for ( Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(ReturnCheck.class) ) {

            //Get return type of the method


        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

I want to get the return type of the annotated method so that I can compare it with the value specified in the annotation.

How can I get the return type of the method ?

Comment: Methods are represented through [`ExecutableElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/ExecutableElement.html)s. You can access the return type through [`ExecutableElement#getReturnType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/ExecutableElement.html#getReturnType()), which will return a [`TypeMirror`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeMirror.html).

Comment: @Pshemo You cannot use reflection for annotation processing.

Comment: @Turing85 Hmm, so that is part of standard Java API which I was unaware of. Good to know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
if (element.getKind() == ElementKind.METHOD) {
    TypeMirror returnType = ((ExecutableElement) element).getReturnType();
    // use returnType for stuff ...
}
```

Explanation:

You can check the `ElementKind` in order to dispatch on its concrete type. This is the recommended way to do it instead of `instanceof`. After that you know its an `ExecutableElement` and can cast it to one.

See [ExecutableElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/ExecutableElement.html), and [Element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.